# rows are multiplied because of joining table?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I am querying "questions" and joining it with "answers". Each question may have two or more answers. Due to which, the number of questions returned are being multiplied by the number of answers. This prevents me from implementing pagination. How can I avoid this? Thanks.

Here is my query:

```
<cfquery name="questions">
    SELECT
       questions.id as questionid,
       questions.question as question,
       questions.rank as rank,
       questions.isrequired as isrequired,
       questiontypes.id AS questiontypeid,
       questiontypes.name as questiontype,
       questiontypes.template as template,
       questions.survey_id as survey_id,
       surveys.name as surveyname,
       surveys.questionsperpage as questionsperpage,
       surveys.thankyoumsg as thankyoumsg,
       answers.id as answerid,
       answers.answer as answer
    FROM
       questions
   LEFT JOIN answers ON answers.question_id = questions.id
   INNER JOIN questiontypes ON questions.questiontype_id = questiontypes.id
   INNER JOIN surveys ON questions.survey_id = surveys.id
   WHERE
   questions.survey_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.surveyid#">  
</cfquery>
```

Comment: A join is always going to return a match per joined row. So a single question with 4 answers (joined) is going to return 4 rows with the question portion duplicated. You could always query twice (once to get question and once to get answers associated with that question). or you could pivot the data to return an `answer1column1` `answer1column2` `answer2column1 `answer2colum2` format.

Comment: Please provide sample data and the results you want.  The rows will be multiplied, if the data requires it.  The question is what you want to do with the results.

Comment: I want to show each question with its answers without multiplying the question column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the ids and answers in comma-delimited lists using `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT
       questions.id as questionid,
       questions.question as question,
       questions.rank as rank,
       questions.isrequired as isrequired,
       questiontypes.id AS questiontypeid,
       questiontypes.name as questiontype,
       questiontypes.template as template,
       questions.survey_id as survey_id,
       surveys.name as surveyname,
       surveys.questionsperpage as questionsperpage,
       surveys.thankyoumsg as thankyoumsg,
       group_concat(answers.id) as answerids,
       group_concat(answers.answer) as answers
    FROM
       questions
   LEFT JOIN answers ON answers.question_id = questions.id
   INNER JOIN questiontypes ON questions.questiontype_id = questiontypes.id
   INNER JOIN surveys ON questions.survey_id = surveys.id
   WHERE
   questions.survey_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.surveyid#">
   group by questions.id
```

Comment: it is showing whole answers with comma delimited with the single question though i am having two question with two answers for each.

Comment: @MSKhan - The above returns *each* question (for the selected survey), along with a comma delimited list of the associated answers: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76555/2/0) . If you are seeing different) results, most likely its either due to your data or a difference in your sql query.

Comment: @MSKhan . . . Did you remember to include the `group by` clause?

Comment: yeah it works fine now.... @Leigh but the problem is while looping inside template it is displaying with comma delimited how can i display with the form of list ?

Comment: Thanks all for your response.

Comment: @MSKhan - Just treat it as a list and cfloop through it. `<cfloop list="#csvListOfAnswers#" index="ans">... do something with #ans# value here </cfloop>` . Note, if your "answer" values can contain commas, you should use a different delimiter with group_concat obviously, because it will cause problems when you cfloop.

Comment: @Leigh -here i have two column with list of values i,e., answer and answerid to be loop over. is there anyway to loop over two lists with single loop ?

Comment: @waseem - You need to use a `from/to` loop, instead of a `list` loop.  But due to the fact that CF ignores empty elements, it is  better to use arrays. Use listToArray() to convert the lists to arrays. Then loop from 1 to the `arrayLen`. Inside the loop, extract the current values from the arrays.  If you run into problems, you should probably open a new question (since this is different issue than in the original question).

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a clarification, but as I mentioned in the comments, the alternatives suggested by Steve and Brad differ from [the "list approach"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18616785/104223) in that they require *two* queries: one to retrieve the id's of the questions to display on the current page, and one to grab the associated answers.

There are different ways to implement it, but one option is using a "grouped" output [as Steve mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18643715/104223). Say you are displaying 10 records per page and want to display results `11` through `20`. First run a query to grab the question id's.

```
    <!---  For clarity these are descriptive, rather than actual, column names --->
    <cfquery name="getCurrentPageQuestions" .....>
        SELECT  QuestionID
        FROM    Questions
        WHERE   SurveyID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.surveyid#"> 
        ORDER BY WhateverColumnsYouWant
        LIMIT  11, 20
    </cfquery>
```

Next, use those id's to filter your original JOIN.  You can skip the filter on survey id because the first query took care of that.

*Important: You **MUST** sort the results by the grouped column first. Otherwise, the grouped cfoutput will not work.*

```
    <cfquery name="getAnswers" .....>
        SELECT
                q.QuestionID
                , q.Question
                , a.AnswerID
                , a.Answer
                , .....
        FROM    questions q
                    LEFT JOIN answers a ON a.questionID = q.questionID
                    INNER JOIN questiontypes qt ON qt.questionTypeID = q.questionTypeID
                    INNER JOIN surveys s ON s.surveyID = q.surveyID
        WHERE  q.questionID IN 
               (
                   <cfqueryparam value="#valueList(getCurrentPageQuestions.questionID)#" 
                        list="true" 
                        cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
               )
        ORDER BY q.questionID
    </cfquery>
```

Finally, use Steve's example to display the results in the proper format:

```
    <cfouput query="getAnswers" group="questionID">
         <!--- display question once --->
        #question#<br>

       <cfoutput> 
            <!--- display all answers --->
             - #answer#<br>
        </cfoutput>
    </cfoutput>
```

Comment: i have used another approach wherein I am storing questions and answers in an Array in  separate queries for each and i was just looping looping the question which has questions ids it is also work fine but i find it hard to do pagination using array that's what i changed my mind. Actually it is the first time I doing pagination for forms with multiple options. anyway thanks for your response.

Comment: Well the above would work just fine for pagination. While I am less fond of lists/arrays, there is no obvious reason [the original approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18616785/104223) would not work too. So if you are having issues, it strongly suggests you are doing something we are not aware of on your end... We would have to see the actual code *and* the output to understand why it did not work for you.  FYI: #CurrentRow# behaves differently with grouped outputs. What do you need it for?

Comment: suppose i have two questions with two answers i want each to be displayed on single page when i want to go for next question on next page it is displaying the same first question with second answer on first page it displays well with all of its answers and it does the same for another questions too  this is my major issue. I haven't problem with CurrentRow i just want to make it clear.

Comment: Are you using the code above? Because I do not see how that could happen. If so, you are almost certainly doing something different in your code. Unfortunately it is impossible say what the difference is without seeing your *actual* code and the results. Feel free to post it, but you should probably open a separate thread - as it is now a different issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36962/discussion-between-leigh-and-waseem)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is tagged ColdFusion.
I would like to propose a ColdFusion graceful solution, that is easier to deal with that comma joined lists.

if you use the <cfoutput>  tag, with attribute query and group
You can output your data hierarchically with 1 question and x answers.

```
<cfouput query="questions" group="questionID">
    #question#<br>
    <cfoutput>
    - #answer#<br>
    </cfoutput>
</cfoutput>
```

You can style this output in divs, or table rows, with a question / answer class that indents them below each other appropriately.

As to the side issue of "prevents me from implementing pagination"
There are too many ways to skin that cat.  I would suggest researching some ajax.
Paginating your questions, and fetching the answers when a user clicks "Show answers"

Comment: *many ways to skin that cat* Yep. Another option is what @Brad suggested in the comments: run two queries. One to paginate based on question ID, then a second query to get the Q&A's for the current page. I like that idea (or something similar) better than lists, because then there are no "delimiter" conflicts.

Comment: I did this at first but still got the problem of repetition of questions so that's what i have to changed my mind.

Comment: @waseem - Which way? I do not think you implemented it the way we we are describing. With the two query approach, the first query only contains "questions" id's. So there are no duplicates. Then use a grouped cfoutput to display the results of the second query (like Steve showed above).

Comment: @waseem did mention above "though i am having two question with two answers for each"  I think you really need to check your data then, maybe you have the questionType in that table twice, or a survey twice, that would cause all rows to duplicate.
Try commenting out each table and it's columns independantly in your SQL GUI, and see which table elimination reduces your duplicates.

Comment: @Steve - I read that a little differently. I took it to mean the question id's were repeated once for each related answer, due to the JOIN with answers. ie So they are not really duplicated. It is exactly what should happen when you JOIN. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76555/4/0) .  As long as he ORDER's BY the question ID, the grouped output should give him the output he wants.

Comment: @Steve - I have no issue regarding displaying questions and its answers, the issue i am figuring out is suppose i have two questions with two answers for each and i want to display each question on single page so what it does here is questions are multiplying with the number of answers as Leigh said above because of this issue I am not sure to use cfoutout query with nested cfoutputs, i have marked the answer above i tried with but i got the problem of looping over two list i,e,. answer and answerid as they are in comma delimited form.

Comment: @waseem - I still think you are misunderstanding the options. The difference between a) the "list" approach and b) what Steve and Brad suggested is that approach "a" can be done with a single query. Approach "b" requires two queries. With Brad's approach, the first query only get's the question id's for the current page. Then second query uses those id's in your original JOIN. By using a "grouped" output, you can format the display properly ie Show the question only *once*, followed by the individual answers.

Comment: @Leigh - If you don't mind will you please show me the Approach "b" ? I mean the code. thanks

Comment: @waseem - There are different ways to slice it, but see [my response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18665701/104223) for one approach. Not tested, so be on the lookout for typos ;-)